# how to use laravel milon / barcode images

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to use the milon / barcodes library to generate barcodes, but I want to generate in png format to save it. I tried it this way:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{DNS1D::getBarcodePNG('Hello World', 'C39')}}" alt="barcode for hello world">
```

but this happens:

[image]

---

I tried that too:

```
\Storage::disk('public')->put('test.png',base64_decode(DNS1D::getBarcodePNG("4", "C39")));
```

and another mistake happens:

[image]

Could someone help me troubleshoot this error? I already made the symbolic link of storage, no more what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The milon package relies on php-gd extension. So, make sure to uncomment ;extension=php_gd2.dll in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just add the barcode image to the laravel blade view?

You can use it like this :

```
<div>{!!DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($model->barcode, 'C128')!!}</div>
```

Where `$model->barcode` is your barcode value ( like : 9913480005777 )

[barcode image in blade view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7yj1.png)